# AMD PSP 2.0 AMD Secure Processor

Tags: security, amd-processor

Simple question or hard,
How run **AMD PSP 2.0** device (AMD Secure Processor) in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://libreboot.org/faq/#amdpsp:

> This is basically AMD's own version of the Intel Management Engine. It
>   has all of the same basic security and freedom issues, although the
>   implementation is wildly different.

Effectively, PSP is an isolated, low-level, proprietary co-processor that cross-checks your BIOS firmware with its own. If the BIOS firmware doesn't contain AMD-PSP firmware, then your computer will not boot.

AMD PSP isn't something that you run- it runs at boot, and while you use your computer. As a matter of fact, it can be quite unsafe- once a cracker gains access to the PSP, he/she can effectively control most, if not all, aspects of your hardware.

You may want to give this a read: https://libreboot.org/faq/#intelme

Comment: Hi,problem is wider , and my apologies I don't provided it. I can't connect with my WiFi card , this is Atheros chipset, and if I try to connect with password I receive message that connection cant be done etc. This is the same in Windows 10 if I don't install this driver. How can I connect by WiFi ?

Comment: @DarofromPoland Huh? AMD PSP has *nothing* to do with your wireless card. Open a new question detailing your issues with your wireless card; I've answered your question here.

Comment: Ok, for sure I check it again in windows 10 if is the same, thx for replies and sorry for disinformation.

Comment: Yes, I confirm you right, It looks it has no matter, I installed this driver in Windows 10 and seems the same , WiFi don't want connect. I receive connection can't be done -etc. Case is solved.